# Need an explanation about Application class

Tags: java, android, class, android-manifest, share

I'm trying to use build-in android's [***Application.class***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), but every time I want to use it, I get a `NullPointerException`. I'm going to share some pieces of code to show how I'm accessing my custom class, which `extends Application`:

This is the class I'm using:

```
public class SharedProperties extends Application {

    private String currentCategory;
    private String dataNews;

    public SharedProperties() {
        super();
    }

    public String getCurrentCategory() {
        return currentCategory;
    }

    public void setCurrentCategory(String currentCategory) {
        this.currentCategory = currentCategory;
    }

    public String getDataNews() {
        return dataNews;
    }

    public void setDataNews(String dataNews) {
        this.dataNews = dataNews;
    }

}
```

...and this how I set and get values from it:

```
    SharedProperties shared = ((SharedProperties)getApplication());
    shared.setCurrentCategory(categories[currentCategory]);
    shared.setDataNews(rssList.get(position).getData());

    ......

    SharedProperties shared = ((SharedProperties)getApplication());
    String category = shared.getCurrentCategory();
    String newstext = shared.getDataNews();
```

Is the way I'm accessing it wrong or I miss something into the `SharedProperties.class`?

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.news.reader"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <application android:name="SharedProperties" android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="News"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can we get the stack trace and manifest declaration?

Comment: What is the purpose of deriving from the Application class?

Comment: @Dan: Should I declare something to AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Jack: I'm passing data through different activities.

Comment: See the answer below by jrobinson3k1

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a `ClassCastException` instead of a `NullPointerException`? If you're getting a null pointer, I doubt it has to do with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `android:name` attribute in the `<application>` entry which contains all your activities, not as a separate entity. Change it to be the fully-qualified name of the class (e.g., `com.this.is.your.package.SharedPreferences`).

Also, don't do this. Use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). *Please*.

Comment: I've already done it with Singleton, but I want to understand why I get `NullPointerException` when I'm using it.

Comment: Why a Singleton?, the Application class of an Android app is a single instance.

Comment: Because allowing the `Application` class to be extended is a relic of Android 1.0 and 1.1. It also is NOT guaranteed to use your extended version of the class during certain Android operations (`BackupManager` comes to mind). Why not just use a separate singleton that you have complete control over?

Comment: @Dan: I mark this answer for a solution because I've declared a second <application> entry and Jake clarifies that I should put it inside "_the <application> entry which contains all your activities_"

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the name of your Application class is `SharedProperties`, not `MyApp`, so it should be cast to that.

Secondly, in order for Android to know to use your custom Application, you need to say so in your `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<application
    android:name="SharedProperties"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: android:name attribute is for your Application class name. jrobinson3k1 is right.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, don exactly remember what i did , but do try adding

```
public SharedProperties()
{

        super();
}
```

Comment: It could be wat jrobinson3k1 told too .Posting logcat trace here would help

Comment: This is already implied. Default constructors are called up the object hierarchy when none is explicitly specified.